# cant "connect" classes in my sublime text 3 python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, sublimetext3

I'm programming in Sublime Text 3 and I need to use an object-oriented class in another class and I can't reach it and its functions from another class (I saved them both on the same directory on my computer), thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we might reproduce the problem ourselves
.

Comment: Did you [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) the other class?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're trying to access one python module from another python module (each "module" is a file), and each module contains a class.

If class A is `Foo`, saved in `foo.py`, and class B is `Bar` saved in `bar.py`, and you want to use `Foo` inside of `Bar`, then you need to `import` `Foo` such that it is in scope when `Bar` is defined.

You might try, in `bar.py`, above where `Bar` is defined: `from foo import Foo`

For more information, this might help: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: thanks but I already tried to import the class, and it doesn't recognize it and its functions.

Answer (score 0):

class1:

```
import sqlite3 

from driver import Driver

from sqlitte import error

def create():

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

except error as e:
    print (e)


c = conn.cursor()
c.excute("""CREATE TABLE users(
    price real,
    discount real
    )""")

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

and class 2(saved in the same directory as driver.py):

```
class Driver:

def __init__(self, online_id):
    self.online_id = online_id


def get_online_id():
    return self.online_id
```